# Java/Weka how to use Selected Tags?

Tags: java, linear-regression, weka

I am trying a simple Linear Regression in Java using the LinearRegression class in Weka. I do not want it to remove any attributes. To set this, it seems to require calling setAttributeSelectionMethod(SelectedTag st). However, what is selectedtag? It seems impossible to change the attribute selection method. Why is doing this not simple as setting some flag or integer?